# ASP.NET AJAX Modal Pop Up Extender - Calling a Method outside of a Listview c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

a bit of a follow on question from this one which helped me greatly.
[ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit ModalPopupExtender inside ListView behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465184/asp-net-ajax-toolkit-modalpopupextender-inside-listview-behavior)

My website is a shop, the products are set up in a class which are called depending on what category they are in. The user can click on the product to get information on it which opens in a new page.

I want to use the modal pop up extender to show this page as a pop up rather than navigate to a new page. 
Thanks to the above link I can almost achieve this, my issue is I cannot call the method "GetProducts" out side of the listview where the panel is.

here is the aspx page

```
    <div id="Panel1" style="display: none;" class="popupConfirmation">
               <iframe id="frameeditexpanse" src="ProductDetails.aspx?productID=<%#:Item.ProductID%>" height="161" > // here is the error item does not exist in the context
               </iframe>
               <div class="popup_Buttons" style="display: none">
                  <input id="btnClose" value="Close" type="button" />
               </div>                                               
           </div>      

    <asp:ListView ID="productList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductID"
    GroupItemCount="3" ItemType="Website.Models.Product" SelectMethod="GetProducts"> // method is called here

     <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="ModalPopupExtender1"
          CancelControlID="btnClose" TargetControlID="PopUpPage"
          PopupControlID="Panel1"  Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" 
          PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" >
     </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>   

<asp:ImageButton ID="PopUpPage" runat="server" 
   src="<%#:Item.ImagePath%>" width="100" height="75" /> // button the user clicks to open the pop up of the product description page
```

and the code behind page if that helps

```
  public partial class ProductList : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts([QueryString("id")] int? categoryId)
        {
            var _db = new Website.Models.ProductContext();
            IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;

            if (categoryId.HasValue && categoryId > 0)
            {

                query = query.Where(p => p.CategoryID == categoryId);
            }
            return query;
        }

    }
```

Ive tried wrapping the iframe in a formview so I can call the method again but that tells me i can only call it once, Ive also tried calling the method in the page load section with no joy, and lots of other things that have cause more errors.

any help would be greatly appreciated.